# C++ Qt - Cannot Install QtWebkit / QtWebkitWidgets

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebkit, qtwebengine

In the past week I tried to upgrade to Qt 5.8 in order to use the QWebEngine, but I had no idea how hard it would be to get Qt Msvc + QWebEngine w/out Visual Studio as the editor. Regardless, I just wanted to go back to Qt 5.6 since it has QtWebkit & QtWebkitWidgets. This proved nearly impossible for me to do on my own. I've been through at least 5 complete re installations, but even though in the Maintenance Tool I choose MinGW & QtWebkit, nothing of the sort actually installs.

Question is:

1. How can I install Qt 5.8 & QWebEngine w/out having to edit all of my code in Visual Studio?

or

2. How can I re install the correct way in order to get QtWebkit to properly install?

Any help is very much appreciated as this has been a struggle for awhile now. Thank you!

Comment: You don't have to use Visual Studio. You can use Qt Creator. But on Windows you do need the MSVC compiler in order to build or use `QWebEngine`. That's a limitation imposed by google, it only builds with the platform's native compiler. MinGW cannot build `QWebEngine`.

Comment: @ddriver Oh wow! i had no idea that you could use the VS Compiler w/ Qt creator. Can you post an answer describing some steps? I'd be glad to accept it!

Comment: You can get the compiler without visual studio for free, a.k.a the build tools: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159

Comment: @ddriver Would I install Qt 5.8.0 via the `qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2015_64-5.8.0` installer?

Comment: Yes, that should work. The MSVC should be automatically detected, so you will just have to select it from the Creator - Build and Run settings.

Comment: @ddriver Adter the install, how should I set up the VS compiler as it usually isn't detected.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't know about that, I haven't used MSVC since 2010. Back then it was automatically detected. There is the option to manually add a compiler, you should look into it, or ask a separate dedicated question.

Comment: @ddriver Thank you very much! This should work fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136650/discussion-between-nicholas-johnson-and-ddriver).